# Generate Sequential IDs for Line Items on a Per Customer Basis in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies if the title is difficult to understand... it proved challenging to summarize my question.

The business has created a self-reporting spreadsheet to give out to our stores to track customer leads. Each row represents one follow-up action, therefor each customer can have multiple rows. Employees were not properly filling out the follow-up counter column (e.g. they'd forget they already spoke to somebody or someone else followed up a previous lead so one customer would have two rows labeled as follow-up #1) so we eliminated it and I'm now using a concatenation of date and sequential rowID column to order their interactions.

I would like to be able to derive follow-up #s with this data. I am now able to easily order the data by Customer, Date, and RowID to get an accurate flow of follow-ups, but I would like to now number those rows 1 through X so I can perform analysis and aggregate on the follow-up counter.

Simplified example of customers ordered with their Date/ID:

[Please click link for example 1 (not enough rep to embed yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQfRe.png)

How could I then, with the data above, create the following:

[Please click link for example 2 (not enough rep to embed yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uPqg.png)

I'd love to be able to derive the follow-up counters after the fact via SQL or T-SQL. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Aside: Typing the data in `code blocks` in the question is better than referring to a picture of the data. It can be seen in context and it can be copied for use in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Window Functions, particularly [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
 [Customer Name],
 [date_id_concat],
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer Name] ORDER BY [date_id_concat]) AS InteractionSeq
FROM
 TABLE;
```

Comment: Elegant and so simple. Thank you so much.